# My index does not display a form field which has been retreived through another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails scaffold for Accounts and another scaffold for Transactions. The Accounts model as an attribute account_name which is created within the form. For each Transaction, the form then prompts a user to select the account the transaction belongs to which is retrieved from the Accounts account_name field. This displays perfectly but when the Transaction is saved, the Account name does not save in the db or display in my index. When I edit the transaction the account name field is set to blank.
Been stuck on this for so damn long - any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**My Account model:**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :transactions

end
```

**My Account form looks like this (and saves perfectly in the DB )**

```
<%= form_for(@account) do |f| %>
  <% if @account.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@account.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this account from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @account.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :account_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :account_name, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :account_number %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :account_number, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

    </div>
    <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </form>

<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

**Transaction Model**

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :accounts

end
```

**The Transaction form looks like (I used the Pluck method to retrieve the Accounts account_name value and it displays all the created accounts):**

```
<div class="form-group">
<%= form_for(@transaction) do |f| %>
  <% if @transaction.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@transaction.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this transaction from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @transaction.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<div class = "jumbotron">
  <form class="needs-validation" novalidate>


    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
    <%= f.label :date %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :date, class:"form-control" %>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
    <%= f.label :reference %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :reference, class:"form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
    <%= f.label :account_name %> <br>
     <%= f.select :account_name, Account.pluck(:account_name), {prompt:"Choose Account"}%>
      </div>


  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">

    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description, class:"form-control" %>
   </div>
   </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
    <%= f.label :amount %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :amount, class:"form-control" %></br>
    </div>

   </br></br></br></br></br></br>
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
   </br> 
    <%= f.label :payment %>
    <%= f.check_box :payment %> | 

    <%= f.label :receipt %>   
    <%= f.check_box :receipt %>

  </div>



 <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**My transaction controller is as follows:**

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_transaction, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /transactions
  # GET /transactions.json
  def index
    @transactions = Transaction.all
    @balance = 0
    @transactions.each do |transaction|
      if transaction.payment == true
        @balance += transaction.amount
      else 
        @balance -= transaction.amount

    end
   end
  end

  # GET /transactions/1
  # GET /transactions/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /transactions/new
  def new
    @transaction = Transaction.new

  end

  # GET /transactions/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /transactions
  # POST /transactions.json
  def create
    @transaction = Transaction.new(transaction_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @transaction.save
        format.html { redirect_to transactions_url, notice: 'Transaction was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @transaction }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @transaction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /transactions/1
  # PATCH/PUT /transactions/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @transaction.update(transaction_params)
        format.html { redirect_to transactions_url, notice: 'Transaction was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @transaction }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @transaction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /transactions/1
  # DELETE /transactions/1.json
  def destroy
    @transaction.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to transactions_url, notice: 'Transaction was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_transaction
      @transaction = Transaction.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def transaction_params
      params.require(:transaction).permit(:date, :description, :reference, :account, :amount, :account_id, :payment, :receipt, account_attributes: [:account_name])
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the usage of [select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/select) method for creating a select tag:

```
<%= f.select :account_name, Account.pluck(:account_name), {prompt:"Choose Account"}%>
```

The second parameter is expected to be an array of two-elements arrays (one for displayed value in the select tag, and another one for the value that is going to be sent as a request parameter).

Thus, the solution you're looking for is going to look something like:

```
<%= f.select :account_name, Account.pluck(:account_name).map { |name| [name, name] }, {prompt:"Choose Account"}%>
```

Or you might want to use [options_from_collection_for_select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) method:

```
<%= f.select :account_name, options_from_collection_for_select(Account.all, :name, :name) %>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Okay so just to be clear, my account_name in both models can be a string type so that when i call it in the transaction form, it will match it to what has been entered? I have that at the moment but still not pulling through.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing that issue because **you need to store the `id` of the account** as a reference in the transaction.

Currently you are saving account name, so it is not prefetching and saving the data

You can use `collection_select` and tell that **save `id` into DB and display `account_name`** in select tag.

**Syntax:**

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

> The `:value_method` and `:text_method` parameters are methods to be called
>   on each member of `collection`. The return values are used as the `value`
>   attribute and contents of each `<option>` tag, respectively.

Here is the `collection_select` in your example:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:account_name,Account.all, :id, :account_name, :prompt => 'Choose Account') %>
```

[**Here is the documentation for the same**](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)

Comment: Please don't use inline code blocks for `arbitrary` words, keep them for actual identifiers. Do use them to match the formatting of sections of other documents you're quoting, especially where they're actually being used correctly.

Comment: yes that `text` is explaining what it does. It is not written by me. anyway changed that to bullet. Thnx. :-)

Comment: Don't put quotes in non-quote blocks, either.

Comment: okay you asked key words to differentiate from the text. fine. Thanks for the suggestion